# Choosing minimum numbers from a given list to give a sum N( repetition allowed)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

How to find the minimum number of ways in which elements taken from a list can sum towards a given number(N)
For example if list = [1,3,7,4] and N=14 function should return 2 as 7+7=14
Again if N= 11, function should return 2 as 7+4 =11. I think I have figured out the  algorithm but unable to implement it in code.
Pls use Python, as that is the only language I understand(at present) 
Sorry!!!

Comment: Please share what you have tried until now

Comment: It's all in my notebook, just pseudo code and steps. Which I know can't be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention dynamic programming in your question, and you say that you have figured out the algorithm, i will just include an implementation of the basic tabular method written in Python without too much theory. 
The idea is to have a tabular structure we will use to compute all possible values we need without having to doing the same computations many times.
The basic formula will try to sum values in the list till we reach the target value, for every target value.

It should work, but you can of course make some optimization like trying to order the list and/or find dividends in order to construct a smaller table and have faster termination.

Here is the code:

```
import sys

# num_list : list of numbers
# value: value for which we want to get the minimum number of addends

def min_sum(num_list, value):

    list_len = len(num_list)

    # We will use the tipycal dynamic programming table construct
    # the key of the list will be the sum value we want, 
    # and the value will be the
    # minimum number of items to sum

    # Base case value = 0, first element of the list is zero   
    value_table = [0]

    # Initialize all table values to MAX
    # for range i use value+1 because python range doesn't include the end
    # number
    for i in range(1, value+1):
        value_table.append(sys.maxsize);

    # try every combination that is smaller than <value>
    for i in range(1, value+1):
        for j in range(0, list_len):
            if (num_list[j] <= i):
                  tmp = value_table[i-num_list[j]]
                  if ((tmp != sys.maxsize) and (tmp + 1 < value_table[i])):
                      value_table[i] = tmp + 1

    return value_table[value]



## TEST ##
num_list = [1,3,16,5,3]
value = 22
print("Min Sum: ",min_sum(num_list,value)) # Outputs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you include your Algorithm in Pseudocode - it will very much look like Python :-)

Another aspect: your first operation is a multiplication with one item from the list (7) and one outside of the list (2), whereas for the second opration it is 7+4 - both values in the list.

Is there a limitation for which operation or which items to use (from within or without the list)?

Comment: I was supposed to write 7+7 not 7×2 my bad. All the elements have to be from the list only. Only addition operation is allowed.